# SSO CAS clients over HTTP

Tags: java, http, tomcat, https, cas

I can't find any documentation on how to run CAS SSO client application on HTTP. I've installed CAS server, it is running on HTTPS, that is OK. But I don't want my client applications to be running on HTTPS. The reason is because they are internal application, there is no need for them to run on HTTPS.

When I am trying to run my client applications on HTTP I am getting the exceptions of SSL handshake, because CAS expecting my application to be running over HTTPS.

Is this even possible to run client application integrated with CAS over HTTP? And if it is how to make this happen?

Specifications:

1. Tomcat 6.0.35
2. JDK 1.6
3. CAS 3.5.1

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The CAS server knows the CAS client applications by the urls patterns defined in its back office and these urls patterns can be HTTP based.

Comment: Do you know how to enable HTTP URL patterns?

Comment: In the `deployerConfigContext.xml`, define a `RegexRegisteredService` which matches HTTP url. For example: `<property name="serviceId" value="^https?://.*" />`